# LitElement lifecycle: before first render

Tags: polymer, lit-element

Is there a way to execute a method exactly after the component has its properties available but before the first render?
I mean something between the class `contructor()` and `firstUpdated()`.
It sounds trivial, maybe in fact I'm missing something trivial..

Comment: You could call a method on the first line of `render` and use a flag to make sure it only runs once or maybe the `connectedCallback` is what you need. (but note that it can also run more than once)

Comment: shouldUpdate is called exactly when you want. But it will be called before every render. So, set a flag to avoid duplicate execution....

Comment: as @mishu mentioned, probably connectedCallback is the closest to what you need, but it depends on what exactly you want to run on that timing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The element's constructor is called when the element is created, either through the HTML parser, or for example through `document.createElement`

The next callback is `connectedCallback` which is called when the DOM node is connected to the document. At this point, you have access to the element's light DOM. Make sure to call `super.connectedCallback()` before doing your own work, as the `LitElement` instance has some work to do here.

The next callback is `shouldUpdate`, which is an optional predicate that informs whether or not LitElement should run its render cycle. Useful if for example, you have a single observed `data` property and destructure deep properties of it in `render`. I've found that it's best to treat this one as a predicate, and not to add all sorts of lifecycle logic inside.

After that, `update` and `render` are called, then `updated` and `firstUpdated`. It's generally considered bad practice to perform side effects in `render`, and the occasions that you really need to override `update` are rare.

In your case, it sounds very much like you should do your work in `connectedCallback`, unless you are relying on LitElement's rendered shadow DOM, in which case, you might consider running your code in `firstUpdated`, then calling `this.requestUpdate()` to force a second update (or changing some observed property in `firstUpdated`)

More info: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle